# PHP get last error

Tags: php, fatal-error

I am trying to recover the last (fatal) error message through these functions:

```
$last_error = error_get_last();
echo $last_error['message'];
```

Using the exception:

```
throw new Exception("Error n.1");
```

I would expect to get this string "Error n.1", but I get something like this (which depends on the PHP version):

```
Uncaught Exception: Error n.1 in C:\wamp\www\JUICE\projects\JATE\dist\jate\functions\errorHandler.php:66 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\JUICE\projects\JATE\dist\jate\functions\requirer.php(37): require_once() #1 C:\wamp\www\JUICE\projects\JATE\dist\jate\functions\requirer.php(5): jRequire('C:\\wamp\\www\\JUI...', false, 0) #2 C:\wamp\www\JUICE\projects\JATE\dist\jate\functions\requirer.php(15): requireComponent('C:\\wamp\\www\\JUI...', false) #3 C:\wamp\www\JUICE\projects\JATE\dist\jate\coreEngine.php(10): requireComponents('functions') #4 C:\wamp\www\JUICE\projects\JATE\examples\01essential\jate.php(15): require_once('C:\\wamp\\www\\JUI...') #5 C:\wamp\www\JUICE\projects\JATE\examples\01essential\index.php(2): require_once('C:\\wamp\\www\\JUI...') #6 {main} thrown
```

How can I get the error string and not all the things added by the system?

Comment: do some string-fu? get the substring after Uncaught exception (and before "in")

Comment: Why aren't you using `try/catch`? Then you can use `$error->getMessage()`.

Comment: @dGRAMOP I can not because the string depends on the version of php the string.

Comment: @Barmar I'm throwing the exceptions, I do not want to capture them!

Comment: Exceptions that are thrown aren't errors. The error is the fact that you didn't catch the exception, and that's what's in `$last_error['message']`.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, so there's no way to separate the exception data from the error data?

Comment: Nope. There's no more structure to `$last_error` than that. The error message is just one string, it's not layered in any way just because the error refers to an exception.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish by using `error_get_last()`? Maybe you could use a regular expression like `if (preg_match('/Error n\.1/', $last_error['message'])`

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to change the style of errors generated by my framework to be better understood by programmers. I can not parse the string because the string changes depending on the php version.

Comment: Sometimes error traces help programmers

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is wrong. Throwing an exception doesn't cause an error by itself, so that's not what is shown in `$last_error`. Failing to catch an exception causes an error, but the message for that error is `Uncaught Exception` followed by the details of the exception, not just the exception string.

Since the specific format of that message is version-dependent, the best you can do is search it for the exception string in it:

```
if (preg_match('/Error n\.1/', $last_error['message']) {
    echo "Error n.1";
}
```